# How to calculate binomial probabilities in Python with very small numbers?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to calculate the likelihood of successfully guessing a password in Python. For example, if we take a 10 character lowercase password (26**10 possible passwords) and we can make 1 billion guesses a second, we can calculate the probability of successfully guessing the password in one hour with:

```py
from scipy.stats import binom
(1 - binom.pmf(k=0, n=1000000000*3600, p=1 / 26**10))
```

Which gives us the the result of `0.02525515384826793` (i.e, 2.5%). However, this doesn't work as we increase the length of the password (or more strictly, as `p` gets closer to zero). For instance if we increase the length of the password to 12 characters:

```py
from scipy.stats import binom
(1 - binom.pmf(k=0, n=1000000000*3600, p=1 / 26**12))
```

Then the returned value is just `0.0`, which is incorrect - presumably due to the float rounding down to zero at some point. How can I calculate this to get a more precise answer?

---

Edit: this was with SciPy 1.10.1. Testing on the latest version (1.11.2 at time of writing) gave the correct value - so it looks like this was an issue with the older version.

Comment: I assume that scipy.stats is working with float64.  Thus you are facing a floating-point error. You could use their [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py) to write your own function based on different dtypes, such as [np.longdouble](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.longdouble)

Comment: With scipy version 1.11.2 on a Mac (m2), the result of `1 - binom.pmf(k=0, n=1000000000*3600, p=1/26**12)` is `3.7723687052348964e-05`, not `0.0`.

Comment: @Gh0stFish, which version of SciPy are you using, and on what platform?  This might be a bug, possibly an old bug that has already been fixed.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser good call. This was with 1.10.1 (Feb 23), which is the version that my distro shipped. But pulling the latest version (1.11.2) from PyPi seemed to resolve this issue - and some of the changelogs talk about improving the precision of statistical distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is about the limitations of floating-point arithmetic which I also often face (i.e, float overflow).

you can use the mpmath library, which provides arbitrary-precision arithmetic:

```
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 50  # Set the desired precision (adjust as needed)
total_passwords = 26**12
guesses_per_second = 1000000000
seconds_in_an_hour = 3600

p = mp.mpf(1) / mp.mpf(total_passwords)
n = mp.mpf(guesses_per_second) * mp.mpf(seconds_in_an_hour)

probability = 1 - mp.power(1 - p, n)
print(float(probability))
```

Extra-Note: Floating-point numbers lose precision even when you are just working with such seemingly harmless numbers like 0.2 or 76.5. You should be extra careful when working with a large amount of floating-point operations over the same data as errors may build up rather quickly.

I hope this can help somehow.

Comment: 76.5 doesn't lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

# Set the precision to a high value (e.g., 1000)
getcontext().prec = 1000

def binomial_probability(n, k, p):
    # Calculate (n choose k) with Decimal precision
    n_choose_k = Decimal(1)
    for i in range(k):
        n_choose_k *= Decimal(n - i) / Decimal(i + 1)
    
    # Calculate the binomial probability
    probability = n_choose_k * (Decimal(p) ** k) * ((Decimal(1) - Decimal(p)) ** (n - k))
    
    return probability

n = 10
k = 2
p = 0.01

result = binomial_probability(n, k, p)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).